# Odoo V14 - lxml.etree.XPathSyntaxError: Invalid predicate

Tags: xpath, report, odoo

I am working on a new module that consists of adding the product weight and the total weight in the stock_picking report, but I have a problem with my xpaths.

The error : `lxml.etree.XPathSyntaxError: Invalid predicate`

I have looked at them very carefully but I can't find what is wrong. Could you please help me?

The code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="report_picking_inherit" inherit_id="stock.report_picking">

         <xpath expr="//td[contains(@t-if, 'has_barcode') and contains(@class, 'text-center')]" position="after">
                <td>
                    <span t-if="o.state != 'done'" t-esc="ml.product_id.weight"/>
                    <span t-if="o.state == 'done'" t-esc="ml.product_id.weight"/>
                </td>
        </xpath>

        <xpath expr="//table[contains(@t-if, 'o.move_line_ids') and contains(@t-if, 'and') and contains(@t-if, 'o.move_ids_without_package')" position="after">
                <span t-field="o.stock_total_weight"/>
        </xpath>

    </template>
</odoo>
```

Thanks by advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "predicate" is the part of the xpath in square brackets, so you want to be looking for the problem there. Looking closer, you have a missing closing square bracket in `//table[contains(@t-if, 'o.move_line_ids') and contains(@t-if, 'and') and contains(@t-if, 'o.move_ids_without_package')`

Try it as

`<xpath expr="//table[contains(@t-if, 'o.move_line_ids') and contains(@t-if, 'and') and contains(@t-if, 'o.move_ids_without_package')]" position="after">`

Answer (score 0):

There has an issue in wrote `xpath`.

In **Odoo** there are **three** types of element locators for matching a target element [Xpath](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/views.html)

Example:

```
<xpath expr="page[@name='pg']/group[@name='gp']/field" position="inside">
    <field name="description"/>
</xpath>

<field name="res_id" position="after"/>

<div name="name" position="replace">
    <div name="name2">
        <field name="name2"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your Code has something like this:

```
<xpath expr="//table[@t-if='o.move_line_ids and o.move_ids_without_package']//tbody//td[@t-if=t-if='has_barcode']" position="after">
    <td>
        <span t-if="o.state != 'done'" t-esc="ml.product_id.weight"/>
        <span t-if="o.state == 'done'" t-esc="ml.product_id.weight"/>
    </td>
</xpath>
```

Comment: SO the problem here is the order i wrote my xpath because it doesn't fit with the code ?